# Using real PID 1 as PID 1 in namespace

Tags: linux

With Linux PID namespaces, is there anyway for the real PID 1 process—not the same executable—to *also* serve as PID 1 in a PID namespace?

Answer (score 2):

No, see `man 7 pid_namespaces`:

> ```
> The namespace init process
>   The first process created in a new namespace (i.e., the process created
>   using clone(2) with the CLONE_NEWPID flag, or the first  child  created
>   by  a  process  after a call to unshare(2) using the CLONE_NEWPID flag)
>   has the PID 1, and  is  the  "init"  process  for  the  namespace  (see
>   init(1)).
> ```

The process with `pid = 1` in a new pid namespaces always comes from new process creation, you can't make an existing process the `init` process in a new pid namespace.